# Find first appearance of a character in a set of possible characters in a string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm aware of the SQL Server `CHARINDEX` function which returns the position of a character (or sub-string) within another string. Still, I did not find any evident that there is support for regular expressions (unless I develop my own UDF).

What I'm looking for is the ability to find the first position of any character in a set within a string.

Example:

```
DECLARE @_Source_String  NVARCHAR(100) = 'This is "MY" string \ and here is more text' ;

SELECT <some function> (@_Source_String,'"\') ;
```

This should return `9` because `"` appears before `\`. On the other hand:

```
SELECT <some function> (@_Source_String,'x\') ;
```

should return `21` because `\` is before `x`.

I should add that **performance** is very important since this function/mechanism will be invoked with very high frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching capabilities in TSQL are pretty basic and often you would require CLR and regular expressions.

You *can* do this requirement with [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) though. A list of characters in square brackets denotes a set of characters to match.

```
DECLARE @_Source_String NVARCHAR(100) = 'This is "MY" string \ and here is more text';

SELECT PATINDEX('%["\]%', @_Source_String),
       PATINDEX('%[x\]%', @_Source_String);
```

Returns

```
+------------------+------------------+
| (No column name) | (No column name) |
+------------------+------------------+
|                9 |               21 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Martin, beautiful (and well suited to my needs) solution. Many thanks!!! (needless to say, up-voted it).

Comment: Martin, one more question: How do I escape a `]` character? Suppose that I'm looking for either `x` or `]`; should I write `PATINDEX('%[x]]]%',...)`?

Comment: @FDavidov - [I don't think this is possible unfortunately](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259534/patindex-missing-escape-clause) - so looks like you will need CLR and regex - or hack around with replacing all instances of `]` with some other character first and add that to the PATINDEX instead.